# How do you determine the boundary curve for Stokes' Theorem

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

In simple examples, such as with a paraboloid, determining the boundary curve is simple enough. However, when I am faced with more complex examples, I seem to get lost and do not know the proper way to proceed. For example, consider the following problem:

Let $M=M_1\cup M_2$ be a surface such that 
$$\begin{align}&M_1:x^2+y^2=4; 0\leq z\leq 1\\&M_2:x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=4;z\geq1\end{align}$$
Given the vector field $\mathbf{F}=(zx+z^2y+5y)\mathbf{\widehat{i}}+(z^3yx+2x)\mathbf{\widehat{j}}+(z^4x^2)\mathbf{\widehat{k}}$, compute
$$\iint_M (\nabla\  \times\ \mathbf{F})\ \cdot\ d\mathbf{S}$$

For this problem, I think it would be too difficult to calculate directly and if we use Stokes' theorem, I don't know what the boundary would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

### Visualzing $M$ and $\partial M$

For how to visualize this without resorting to a computer, observe the following:

- $M_1$ is a cylinder of radius $2$ about the $z$-axis. $\partial M_1$ is a pair of circles in the  $z=0$ and $z=1$ planes.
- $M_2$ is part of a sphere with radius $2$ centered at $(0,0,1)$. The domain restriction of $z\geq 1$ shows this to be the "upper hemisphere." $\partial M_2$ is a circle of radius $2$ in the $z=1$ plane.
- $\partial M_2$ is precisely the portion of $\partial M_1$ in the $z=1$ plane. As such, $\partial M$ is a circle of radius $2$ centered about the origin on the $z=0$ plane (i.e., the $xy$-plane).

For reference, here's what a graph of your surface $M$ looks like, with $M_1$ in orange, $M_2$ in blue, and $\partial M$ in red:

[image]

Assuming that $M$ is oriented with outward pointing normal vectors, the induced boundary orientation is counter-clockwise (as viewed from the $+z$-direction). As such, we can parametrize $\partial M$ by $$\gamma: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3, ~\gamma(t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, 0).$$

### Using Stokes' Theorem

Now that we have parametrized $\partial M$ with the correct orientation, we can reduce the flux integral to a vector line integral:
\begin{align*}
&\iint_M (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec{S}\\
 &= \oint_{\partial M} (zx + z^2 y +5y) \mathrm{d}x + (z^3yx + 2x) \mathrm{d}y + (z^4 x^2) \mathrm{d}z \\
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \left\langle 0 + 0 + 5 *2 \sin t, 0 + 2*2 \cos t, 0 \right\rangle \cdot \left\langle -2 \sin t, 2 \cos t, 0 \right\rangle \mathrm{d} t \\
 &= \int_0^{2 \pi} -20 \sin^2 t +8 \cos^2 t ~\mathrm{d}t \\
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} -28 \sin^2 t + 8 (\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t) ~\mathrm{d}t \\
 &= -28 \pi + 16 \pi \\
 &= -12 \pi
\end{align*}

Comment: That graphic is awesome! What did you use to generate it?

Comment: Mathematica, in particular the `ContourPlot3D` and `ParametricPlot3D` commands.

Comment: thanks! However, regarding the boundary, I still don't quite know how it works. In general, is the boundary just all of the sharp edges of the solid? and then in this case, because the bottom edge of the hemisphere and top edge of the cylinder are the same, they cancel out?

Comment: Almost. Imagine being a tiny ant walking around on this surface. The boundary is anywhere that your ant is in danger of "falling off the edge of the earth." The circle in the $xy$-plane represents such a place. A precise definition would be anywhere that locally looks like $\{(x,y) ~|~y \geq 0 \}$. "Sharp edges" is a bit vague; it could just mean a point where the surface isn't differentiable.

Comment: For another analogy, "kinks" in the surface aren't part of the boundary. Also, $\partial [0,2] = \{0,2\}$ and $\partial [1,3] = \{1,3\}$ but $\partial ([0,2] \cup [1,3]) = \partial [0,3] = \{0,3\}$.